# Is there an open source JDBC driver for Cassandra?

Tags: jdbc, cassandra

I am looking for an open source free to distribute JDBC driver for Cassandra. I have worked with Simba JDBC driver but this isn't freely distributable. Is there any recommendation on a popular open source driver?

Comment: Asking for recommendations for libraries is off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I am not aware of any open-source JDBC driver for Cassandra in existence.

The JDBC driver from Magnitude (formerly Simba) is paid for by DataStax and DataStax then distributes it to users at no cost.

Maintaining drivers is quite expensive so there are hardly any groups willing to invest resources in it. There are very few exceptions like the authors of GoCQL.

Full disclosure: I work at DataStax so I have an insight on it. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks Erick for your response,

Comment: Happy to help, mate. Cheers! 